# Seperate timeseries in pandas and give ID to each timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe with the following form:

```
datetime   sensor1_value  sensor2_value
```

where `datetime` is the index which starts and ends on a certain day (chronological order). 
This gives me a number of timeseries with an unequal number of measurements.

I want to give each timeseries (24h = one series) a certain ID so my final `df` should look like

```
datetime   ID   sensor1_value  sensor2_value
```

Everything with ID = 1 belongs to timeseries 1 (day 1)

Everything with ID = 2 belongs to timeseries 2 (day 2)

and so on.

So far i have tried to group the df with

```py
dflist = []

for group in df.groupby(df.index.date):
    dflist.append(group[1])
```

which gives me a list of all dataframes, but not one df for all data. I could not figure out how to get everything together and add the ID.

Comment: Could you please provide an example with some sample data for others to check easily ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. I have reconstructed the data frame as one was not provided.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
times = pd.date_range(start ='1/1/2020',end='1/20/2020',periods = 100)
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(times, np.random.uniform(size = 100), np.random.uniform(size = 100))), 
                  columns = ['datetime', 'sensor_1_value', 'sensor_2_value'])
df['date_only'] = df.datetime.dt.date
df['ID'] = df.groupby(['date_only']).ngroup() + 1
```